# angularjs table refresh from model pop up

Tags: angularjs, database, angular-ui-bootstrap

How to accomplish refreshing the table after $uibModel is closed ?

I am using $uibModel open method to pass the required data to Model.

The data from the Model shown gets saved, but the table does not get refresh.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: following code opne ths Model
var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
         
// code to initialize 
        });
        modalInstance.result.then(function (response) {
          
        $log.debug('Reload data')
         $scope.reloadAttributes();
                                
                }, function () {
              $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
                });

Comment: Save button function on Model that gets pop up.
    
       
    // called when Save button is clicked
     $scope.save = function () {
            attributeService.Save($scope.attribute).then(function (data) {
                    $log.debug('Saved complete');
                }, function (data) {
               $log.debug('Error saving data');
            })
            $uibModalInstance.close($scope.attribute);
            }

Comment: In the console I see data as 
    Reload data
    Saved complete
    
    This means , reload is getting executed before Save is complete.
    
    How to make ReLoad wait untill Save is completed ?

Comment: My apologize for adding the code in comment. Stackover kept giving me error as ...it looks like your post is mostly code.... Spent almost 30 minutes to resolve. But had no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I will try. As far as I understand, you want to save your changes prior to calling the `$scope.reloadAttributes();`. If that's the case, then just call the modal `close` in success callback for `attributeService.Save()` method, like this (copied your code from comments):

```
$scope.save = function () { 
  attributeService.Save($scope.attribute)
    .then(function (data) {
      $log.debug('Saved complete');
      $uibModalInstance.close($scope.attribute);
    }, 
    function (data) {
      $log.debug('Error saving data'); 
    });
}
```

I don't know what would you like to happen in case `attributeService.Save()` has failed (close popup? show error?) but it should be clear by now, how to do it.